# Roblox: How to kill player if they don't complete a task correctly?

Tags: roblox

I'm using a pre-made code door in which the player(s) must enter correct passwords to pass through. I would like the last door the local player must go through to kill them if they guess the password wrong. The door is a 2323 code door. It already came with a script. I've tried to edit the code for the incorrect password:

```
Input = ""
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character
character.health = 0
print("Wrong Code")
```

However, I get a nil value "Character."
Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is this code in a Script or a LocalScript?

Comment: It appears to be just a script based on the icon that it has.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access localplayer from a server script. Here is what you can do alternatively:

1. Make server script
2. Make a remote event
3. Fire the remote event with the password as the arg
4. Put this in your server script:

```lua
local remoteevent = -- reference remote event path here
local correctpass = 2323

remoteevent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(p, pass)
    -- p is player and pass is the password the user entered
    if tonumber(pass) == correctpass then
        -- User entered correct pass so open the door
    else
        p.Character.Humanoid.Health = 0
    end
end)
```

And finally, fire the remote event from the local script just like this:

```lua
local remoteevent = -- reference remote event path here
local userinput = -- get the password the user entered here
remoteevent:FireServer(userinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Local (damage 100)
Local if seen @e player chase